# How do I change the default behavior of my dropdown menus in bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a [template](https://demos.creative-tim.com/light-bootstrap-dashboard-pro/examples/dashboard.html?_ga=2.30458175.1003293307.1592246814-1127470210.1592246814) that makes use of Boostrap 4.Currently it's drop-down elements are using the dropdown menu with a little triangle at the left side, and a popout animation. I'd like to change this to a dropdown menu that is flat at the top and has no animation (or a simple slide). Where do I change this setting?

Comment: can you reference the template you are asking about?

Comment: @Mech Sorry, I edited the post to include the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For these modifications, navigate to `/assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard.css`.

---

To remove the animation, remove:

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .dropdown-menu,
.dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
    -moz-transform: scale(0);
    -o-transform: scale(0);
    -ms-transform: scale(0);
    transform: scale(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 370ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 370ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
    -o-transition: all 370ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 370ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
    transition: all 370ms cubic-bezier(0.34, 1.61, 0.7, 1);
}
```

---

To remove the triangle, remove all of the following:

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .dropdown-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 11px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: -11px;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-item .dropdown-menu:after {
    border-bottom: 11px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-left: 11px solid transparent;
    border-right: 11px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 12px;
    top: -10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much; the last part wasn't in reference to the rounded corners, but the triangle at the top-left part of the drop-down menu that points to the navbar item. Basically I'd like the dropdown menu to look like it does here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/, rather how it looks now.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. I saw "flat top" and went with it :) I've updated the answer.

Comment: Mech, thank you so much!! This was such a headache for me to try and track down! I wish I could give you more upvotes for this lol.

Comment: Glad I could help :)